# Pandas how to outer merge on datetime column correctly

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two dataframes:

```
resetted.head()
WeightedSentiment   Popularity  Datetime
0   0   2   2012-11-22 11:00:00
1   0   2   2012-11-22 11:30:00
2   0   4   2012-11-22 12:00:00
3   0   2   2012-11-22 15:00:00
4   0   2   2012-11-22 15:30:00

prices.head()
Open    High    Low     Close   Volume  Datetime
46623   236.9392    238.6095    236.5392    238.2094    315177  2012-11-23 10:00:00
46624   238.1894    238.3095    236.7492    237.4993    122132  2012-11-23 10:30:00
46625   237.4793    238.2595    237.1393    238.2094    144457  2012-11-23 11:00:00
46626   238.2094    238.9196    238.1694    238.7695    131733  2012-11-23 11:30:00
46627   238.7695    239.1396    237.9394    238.9496    150386  2012-11-23 12:00:00
```

And I tried to outer join these two dataframes, but by using

`pd.merge(prices,resetted,how='outer',on='Datetime')`

The result is very strange and seems wrong:

```
Open    High    Low     Close   Volume  Datetime    WeightedSentiment   Popularity
0   236.9392    238.6095    236.5392    238.2094    315177.0    2012-11-23 10:00:00     0.0     20.0
1   238.1894    238.3095    236.7492    237.4993    122132.0    2012-11-23 10:30:00     0.0     12.0
2   237.4793    238.2595    237.1393    238.2094    144457.0    2012-11-23 11:00:00     0.0     12.0
3   238.2094    238.9196    238.1694    238.7695    131733.0    2012-11-23 11:30:00     0.0     2.0
4   238.7695    239.1396    237.9394    238.9496    150386.0    2012-11-23 12:00:00     0.0     12.0
5   238.7995    242.0301    238.0394    241.5900    1183601.0   2012-11-23 12:30:00     0.0     16.0
```

If I swap the two dataframes' position in the merge function, there will be NaN at head as expected, but the other rows are wrong. I have setup a demo notebook on [github](https://github.com/xg-wang/pandas-demo/blob/master/Untitled.ipynb).

I'm on pandas 0.21.0

Comment: The merge looks correct when I run it locally.  Are you sure your `Datetime` fields are actually `Datetime` objects?  If I allow them to be strings, the merged `Datetime` values look funny.

Comment: @andrew_reece hi andrew, I updated the question with the notebook link, pretty sure it was datetime.

Comment: Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: ...Sorry I just noticed that I should add `sorted=True`, otherwise the ouput order is messed up. Thank you!